# When using the Repository Pattern in Java, is it ok to use a single Manager/Controller for 3 different Repositories?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, repository-design

I have 3 repositories that need to communicate with each other. Can I handle the logic of all 3 repositories in a single Manager or is it a better practice to create different Managers for each Repository and make them communicate with each other using another Manager (that will directly communicate with the UI)?

**Context:**

It's basically an app for managing restaurant orders.

The 3 Repositories are:

- **ProductRepository**  - the available products
- **TableRepository**  - all the tables in the restaurant
- **OrderRepository**  - one order consists of a tuple (product_id, table_id)

The manager must validate the data, create Product, Table and Order objects and save them to the correct Repository.

Comment: please show and example of code in terms of what you attempted?

Comment: Add a little more background, or maybe some concrete (example) pieces. What these repositories represent. And how they depend up on one other.

Comment: Added some details to the question.

Comment: Are you implementing a transaction script or a domain model? What's the exact use case and invariants that need to be protected?

Answer (score -1):

If classes / resources depend up on one other, there is (these days) mostly a [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) framework, handling the creation of these resources, and also Injecting them, in those who need them.

The best known DI libraries for Java are

- [Google Guice](https://github.com/google/guice)
- [Spring DI](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm)